# Does Mafia 3 have the option for Lincoln to drive himself?

Tags: mafia-3

In Mafia 2 once you got in the car you could choose for the computer to drive you to your destination.

Is this a feature in Mafia 3?

Answer (score 1):

No it isn't. No fast travel (i.e. like GTA V taxis) either. Having said that the fastest cars do about MACH 3 so it doesn't take too long to get around.